# White / blank page on Skype after login

Tags: skype

I'm using 14.04. Since I have updated system, with whom an update of Skype came, few days ago. Problem is when I log in into Skype (skypeforlinux) it shows my chats and contacts for 2 seconds and then window becomes white - blank, I can only see its borders. The same thing happens if I am logged in on Unity, GNOME fallback, Compiz or Metacity. I've tried to remove the app and the config directory, installed it again but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I have downloaded it from their official page as a .deb and did dpkg -i <package name>, when i was removing it i did dpkg -P <package name> and i have also deleted skypeforlinux folder in .config. And installed it the same way like first time. I have even made a VM with 17.10 and installed it there and it works perfectly. Also on some other site i have read that people say that they have this issue with xfce desktop.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy skypeforlinux`? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, @DavidFoerster, I have exactly the same problem. When I launch Skype I see only the borders of its window. So I must minimize and maximize it to see the content of the window. Here is the output of `apt-cache policy skypeforlinux` within my system: https://paste.ubuntu.com/25895182/. If you have any ideas I would ask a separate question.

Comment: Issue was resolved with todays skype update

Comment: Same problem with version 8.13.0.2

Comment: Solved my problem with `sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux=8.11.0.4`